# Problem with PHP mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

When I run **mysql_real_escape_string** , for example like this:

```
$test = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['test']);
```

it's not working on local server, it gives me an error page!

- my local server is "**AppServ**".
- my operating systim is "**windows XP**".

Is this normal ? and just i have to run it on hosted site only !

Comment: Try **mysql_escape_string** please

Comment: windows message pop up with this "HTTP apache server has problem with send & don't send buttons" when i click on don't send the browser gives me "cannot load this page".

Comment: That error seems nothing to do with escaping. Did you try running your script without `mysql_real_escape_string`? Does it produce the same error even then?

Comment: yes I ran it without mysql_real_escape_string and its worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the function an active database connection. I think it's the second argument:

```
$test = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['test'], $mysql_database_connection);
```

That might be your error, because if you don't provide an active connection explicitly, the function looks for the last one which was created. If you run this function *before* connecting to the database, it'll give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to know which error before we could help you any more, but the most common error that I get when using `mysql_real_escape_string` is when I forget that [it takes a second parameter](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

This tells the function which character set you need escaping. You just need to pass the database resource ID.